# Install and configure lighttpd on diferent port than apache on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, lighttpd

I have ubuntu server and installed Apache and PHP. All my web works fine.

I want images, from the web, to work with lighttpd server on different port than apache,
for example 8080. So, in html I will have

```
    <img src="http://myweb.com:8080/@content/img.jpg" />
```

How to install and configure lighttpd without disrupting apache ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a site for professionals. We don't mind helping if you're stuck, but you have to show that you've at least put a little tiny drop of effort into solving your problem.

Comment: I can install lighttpd an configure to work with another port but if that disrupting apache than I will have a problem...

Comment: How would it disrupt apache other than contending for resources?

Comment: Ok , I will try that now. I don't want to post some crap on this web so if it is, vote down to delete...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `server.port` to 8080 in the lighttpd config.